# Oracle ORDS OAuth2, 500 error with “String length must be a multiple of four” from oracle.dbtools.common.util.Base64.base64ToByteArray

Tags: java, oracle, oauth, fetch-api, oracle-ords

My need is to obtain a token from Oracle ORDS with an already authenticated user. I am following [this documentation](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-authentication#oauth2-client-credentials) to dev a javascript using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

I am stuck at the point

> $ curl -i -k --user 3NvJRo_a0UwGKx7Q-kivtA..:F5WVwyrWxXj3ykmhSONldQ..
>   --data "grant_type=client_credentials" https://ol7-121.localdomain:8443/ords/pdb1/testuser1/oauth/token
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>   Content-Type: application/json Transfer-Encoding: chunked Date: Wed,
>   29 Jun 2016 12:07:02 GMT
>
> {"access_token":"-zYl-sFyB2iLicAHw2TsRA..","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600}
>   $

Based on this example i set *my curl* as below and test it in my host's command line and **it responds with a valid token as expected**

```
curl -i -k --user Uj1xXqz5pNRoSubJ6v3Hdg..:Npvid_qzM75NrO978NKl0A.. --data "grant_type=client_credentials" http://myhost:8080/ords/myrest/oauth/token
```

Next I try to *convert* the verified curl commad as a fetch request in this way but it responds with a **500 Internal Server Error**:

```
fetch('http://myhost:8080/ords/myrest/oauth/token',
{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic Uj1xXqz5pNRoSubJ6v3Hdg..:Npvid_qzM75NrO978NKl0A..'
    },
    body: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
})...
```

I can't figure it out what I am doing wrong or what I am missing although I am searching and trying different variations.
Advices and suggestions will be appreciated.

************ EDIT : Following advices in comments I try to go some steps further ************

About the **OPTIONS** request I inspect the network activity (as a first try I use developer tools of browser) and I found the headers with method OPTIONS and status code 200.

After that considering that I have deployed ORDS via Tomcat, I modify *default.xml* in /app/oracle/ora_rest/params as stated in [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37099_01/doc.20/e25066/trouble.htm#AELIG7206). Now I am able to retrive e full description of the error and I am still trying to config/inspect logs.

The full trace of the error is :

> InternalServerException [statusCode=500, reasons=[An unexpected error with the following message occurred: String length must be a multiple of four.]]
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.errors.ServletResponseExceptionMapper.mapError(ServletResponseExceptionMapper.java:84)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.errors.ErrorPageRenderer.(ErrorPageRenderer.java:43)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.errors.ErrorPageRenderer.(ErrorPageRenderer.java:35)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.errors.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.ForceAuthFilter.doFilter(ForceAuthFilter.java:44)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.Filters.filter(Filters.java:47)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPoint.service(EntryPoint.java:82)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPointServlet.service(EntryPointServlet.java:49)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>       at oracle.dbtools.rt.web.HttpEndpointBase.dispatchableServices(HttpEndpointBase.java:116)
>       at oracle.dbtools.rt.web.HttpEndpointBase.service(HttpEndpointBase.java:81)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1354)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: String length must be a multiple of four.
>       at oracle.dbtools.common.util.Base64.base64ToByteArray(Base64.java:43)
>       at oracle.dbtools.common.util.Base64.base64ToByteArray(Base64.java:23)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.HttpBasicAuthenticationHandler.extractCredentials(HttpBasicAuthenticationHandler.java:38)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.HttpBasicAuthenticationHandler.(HttpBasicAuthenticationHandler.java:21)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.HttpBasicAuthentication.(HttpBasicAuthentication.java:15)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.AuthenticationFilter.authenticate(AuthenticationFilter.java:69)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:62)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
>       at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.RequestMapperImpl.doFilter(RequestMapperImpl.java:125)
>       at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.URLMappingBase.doFilter(URLMappingBase.java:103)
>       at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.filter.URLMappingFilter.doFilter(URLMappingFilter.java:124)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.cors.CORSResponseFilter.doFilter(CORSResponseFilter.java:83)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpResponseFilter.doFilter(HttpResponseFilter.java:45)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
>       at oracle.dbtools.http.errors.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:94)
>       ... 34 more

Comment: Try instead `curl -X OPTIONS` with that same URL and parameters — because your browser is sending an OPTIONS request before ever even trying the POST request from your code. A CORS preflight OPTIONS request. And it’s doing that because you’re adding an Authorization header to the request.

Comment: @sideshowbarker : thanks for your reply, I edit my question because of your comment. Maybe I don't focus on what was my problem. I don't need a curl command but from a verified one I need to set a javascript fetch option object.

Comment: do you have access to the ords logs? it should show what's happening behind the 500s

Comment: I realize you don’t need a curl command. What I’m telling you is that if you want to try to reproduce the 500 error with curl, you need to make curl send an OPTIONS request. Because the 500 error you’re getting in the browser is a response to an OPTIONS request, not a response to a POST request. Anyway, as @thatjeffsmith points out, you should inspect that server logs to see what information the server is logging when whatever internal server failure happens that causes the server to respond with a 500 error.

Comment: At this point I edit/update my answer for better documentation

Answer (score 1):

The line

> **[...]Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: String length must be a multiple of four.   at
>   oracle.dbtools.common.util.Base64.base64ToByteArray(Base64.java:43)
>   [...]**

lead me to modify the request headers passing the **client_id:client_secret (authdata) base64 converted (window.btoa(authdata))**, like this way:

```
fetch('http://myhost:8080/ords/myrest/oauth/token',
    {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa(authdata),
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
    })...
```

The fetch is now responding correctly with the access_token value and I can use it to make authorized GET requests.